# application.yml file not loading during junit4 testing, spring boot-1.2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit4

Writing test on controller calss. Controller class uses variables mentioned in application.yml file via @Value annotation.
On running junit test, my test class makes a call to controller endpoint/method. It fails because when method logic comes across  those variables and gets null values.
Spring Boot Version - 1.2.0
Junit 4

This is my **Test class**, calling Controller method via MockMVC.perform

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) // Using Powermockito in test logic
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
@PrepareForTest(RestUtils.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes =<main_class>.class, 
initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class TestClass{
    ......
mockmvc.perform(get("/getRegisteredDevices/SYR")
                 .header("Authorization", Auth)
                 .header("AUTH-MODE", "Basic")
                 .param("serviceAccount", "SYR")
                 .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                
                 ).andExpect(status().isOk());
    
    }
```

This is my **controller class**

```
    public class DeviceRegistrationController {
    @Value("${oauth2.introspect}")
        String oauth2IntrospectURL;
        
        @Value("${pf.clientAuth}")
        String pfClientAuth;
        
        @Value("${accesstoken.managerid}")
        String accessTokenMgrId;
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getRegisteredDevices/{serviceAccount}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<DeviceRegistrationResp> getRegisteredDeviceList(
                @ApiParam(name = "Authorization", value = "user authorization header , required = true) @RequestHeader("Authorization") String credentials,
                @RequestHeader("AUTH-MODE") String auth_mode,
                @ApiParam(name = "serviceAccount", value = "Service account aginst which the devices will be registered", required = true) @PathVariable String serviceAccount)
 {
String token="Bearer" + oauth2IntrospectURL;
// oauth2IntrospectURL comes out as null  and hampers further logic
    }
    }
```

Comment: Include code. In particular, show how you're making that "call", and (if using MockMvc) how you obtain your instance.

Comment: I edited it, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

without any informations on how your application.yml is used it is difficult to help you,

but be sure that your are not using the same application.yml for your test, a best practice is to create another applications.yml for test purposes in `src/test/resources/application.yml`

Comment: yes, i tried putting application.yml (also application-test.yml) in that location, didn't work out for me. Also tried @ActiveProfiles("test"), didn't work. Also used @TestPropertySource(classpath:application-test.yml), didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that the test is not running as a Spring Boot Test and hence won't wire and populate the @Values. Annotations like these may help:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyTestClass(){
   ...
```

Comment: my spring boot version is 1.2.0, @SpringBootTest i have tried, works after 1.4.0    https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html, please tell me if i am wrong